# Setting query greater than previously declared limit

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to declare 2 queries: one that has a limit of the first 6 entries, and the other that displays the rest of the entries. Is this possible? How can one do so?

Here is my code:

```
// displays the first 6 entries
$Student_Names = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT Student_First_Name, Student_Last_Name FROM Student LIMIT 6");

// how to display rest of table entries Excluding the first 6 displayed above
$Student_Names_Full = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT Student_First_Name, Student_Last_Name FROM Student");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use OFFSET

```
$Student_Names_Full = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT Student_First_Name, Student_Last_Name FROM Student LIMIT 9999 OFFSET 6");
```

you have to choose best value for limit.

Comment: Limit & offset in this way are not useful if they don´t have and ORDER BY. There is no way to be sure that the second query excludes the students in the first query unless you use an ORDER BY